# Why does this shorter way of calling a PHP function with an array reference lead to a different result?

Tags: php, pass-by-reference

If a function `my_func` is defined as:

```
function my_func(&$arr) {
    array_push($arr, 0);
    array_push($arr, 1);
    array_push($arr, 2);
    array_push($arr, 3);
    array_push($arr, 4);
}
```

If I call `my_func` as follows, then the results are as expected:

```
$test_array = array();
my_func($test_array);
print_r($test_array);
```

Results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 0
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
    [3] => 3
    [4] => 4
)
```

I was thinking that I could shorten this code somewhat by calling `my_func` as follows:

```
my_func($test_array = array());
print_r($test_array);
```

However, the result changes:

```
Array
(
)
```

Why does this shorter code snippet lead to a different result?

Comment: See: http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php (last code block, `foo($a = 5); // Expression, not variable`).

Comment: I must admit, there are always exceptions in php like this one that look like they "should" work... but something in the inner workings of PHP messes it up :( eventually you remember them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not passing the *variable* by reference, but the value of an *expression*.

If you were to enable all errors, you would see the following message:

```
Strict Standards: Only variables should be passed by reference in
```

The value of an assignment is the value that is being assigned itself. It is that value—a copy of the array—that gets passed to `my_func`.

The [**PHP documentation on the matter**](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php) puts this more strongly:

> No other expressions should be passed by reference, as the **result is undefined**.

**Conclusion**: Only ever pass variables (`$x`, `$x[0]`, `$x->a`), new objects or references returned from functions *to* a function expecting a reference.

Comment: If i didn't lose 2 rep points, i would downvote this purely on the basis of it's you again :p good answer though :)

Comment: @VBAssassin Well, I'd say you shouldn't leave empty handed, but if that's no trouble I'll gladly take an upvote instead ;)

Comment: maybe next time since we now we're even because i'm sure you downvoted my answer to that other question :p if you didn't... ah well lol

Comment: @VBAssassin No, I did not downvote that answer of yours. If I downvoted every answer I had something to complain about, I'd have no rep left ;)